# Firefox OS Facebook login return

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, operating-system

I'm creating an Firefox OS app that uses Facebook API (js sdk).

To login, I'm using this button:

```
<a role="button" class="blue" id="loginButton" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=API_KEY&redirect_uri=RETURN_URL">
     Login with Facebook
</a>
```

I want to make an app that works without a server side (only client - I'm using firebase as server side).

But, when I click on the button, it sends me to the login page. When I sign in, it redirects me to a url, but I don't have a url to return (I'm creating an compacted app, not a hosted app).

Is there a way to do that, or do I need to host the app and redirect there?

Thanks!